# Find correct 2D translation of a subset of coordinates

Tags: r

I have a problem I wish to solve in R with example data below. I know this must have been solved many times but I have not been able to find a solution that works for me in R.

The core of what I want to do is to find how to translate a set of 2D coordinates to best fit into an other, larger, set of 2D coordinates. Imagine for example having a Polaroid photo of a small piece of the starry sky with you out at night, and you want to hold it up in a position so they match the stars' current positions.

Here is how to generate data similar to my real problem:

```
# create reference points (the "starry sky")
set.seed(99)
ref_coords = data.frame(x = runif(50,0,100), y = runif(50,0,100))

# generate points take subset of coordinates to serve as points we 
# are looking for ("the Polaroid")
my_coords_final = ref_coords[c(5,12,15,24,31,34,48,49),]

# add a little bit of variation as compared to reference points 
# (data should very similar, but have a little bit of noise)
set.seed(100)
my_coords_final$x = my_coords_final$x+rnorm(8,0,.1)
set.seed(101)
my_coords_final$y = my_coords_final$y+rnorm(8,0,.1)

# create "start values" by, e.g., translating the points we are 
# looking for to start at (0,0)  
my_coords_start =apply(my_coords_final,2,function(x) x-min(x))

# Plot of example data, goal is to find the dotted vector that 
# corresponds to the translation needed
plot(ref_coords, cex = 1.2) # "Starry sky"
points(my_coords_start,pch=20, col = "red") # start position of "Polaroid"
points(my_coords_final,pch=20, col = "blue") # corrected position of "Polaroid"
segments(my_coords_start[1,1],my_coords_start[1,2],
my_coords_final[1,1],my_coords_final[1,2],lty="dotted")
```

Plotting the data as above should yield:
[image: Open points are the starry sky, red dots my Polaroid when I first come out, blue dots when is Polaroid after I manage to mach it to the sky]

The result I want is basically what the dotted line in the plot above represents, i.e. a delta in x and y that I could apply to the start coordinates to move them to their correct position in the reference grid.

**Details about the real data**

There should be close to no rotational or scaling difference between my points and the reference points.

My real data is around 1000 reference points and up to a few hundred points to search (could use less if more efficient)

I expect to have to search about 10 to 20 sets of reference points to find my match, as many of the reference sets will not contain my points.

Thank you for your time, I'd really appreciate any input!

**EDIT:** To clarify, the right plot represent the reference data. The left plot represents the points that I want to translate across the reference data in order to find a position where they best match the reference. That position, in this case, is represented by the blue dots in the previous figure.

Finally, any working strategy must not use the data in `my_coords_final`, but rather reproduce that set of coordinates starting from `my_coords_start` using `ref_coords`.

[image: start positions and reference data]

Answer (score 1):

So, the previous approach I posted (see edit history) using `optim()` to minimize the sum of distances between points will only work in the limited circumstance where the point distribution used as reference data is in the middle of the point field.  The solution that satisfies the question and seems to still be workable for a few thousand points, would be a brute-force delta and comparison algorithm that calculates the differences between each point in the field against a single point of the reference data and then determines how many of the rest of the reference data are within a minimum threshold (which is needed to account for the noise in the data):

```
##  A brute-force approach where min_dist can be used to 
##    ameliorate some random noise:
min_dist <- 5 
win_thresh <- 0
win_thresh_old <- 0
for(i in 1:nrow(ref_coords)) {
  x2 <- my_coords_start[,1]
  y2 <- my_coords_start[,2]
  x1 <- ref_coords[,1] + (x2[1] - ref_coords[i,1])
  y1 <- ref_coords[,2] + (y2[1] - ref_coords[i,2])

  ##  Calculate all pairwise distances between reference and field data:
  dists <- dist( cbind( c(x1, x2), c(y1, y2) ), "euclidean")

  ##  Only take distances for the sampled data:
  dists <- as.matrix(dists)[-1*1:length(x1),]

  ##  Calculate the number of distances within the minimum
  ##    distance threshold minus the diagonal portion:
  win_thresh <- sum(rowSums(dists < min_dist) > 1)  

  ##  If we have more "matches" than our best then calculate a new
  ##    dx and dy:
  if (win_thresh > win_thresh_old) {
    win_thresh_old <- win_thresh
    dx <- (x2[1] - ref_coords[i,1])
    dy <- (y2[1] - ref_coords[i,2])
  }
}

##  Plot estimated correction (your delta x and delta y) calculated
##    from the brute force calculation of shifts:
points(
  x=ref_coords[,1] + dx, 
  y=ref_coords[,2] + dy,
  cex=1.5, col = "red"
)
```

[image]

I'm very interested to know if there's anyone that solves this in a more efficient manner for the number of points in the test data, possibly using a statistical or optimization algorithm.

Comment: Thank you Forrest, but I now realize that I was unclear in my question. In my real case I don't have the 'my_final_coords' data frame. So the real issue is to find the vector that I can apply on 'my_start_coords' to translate it into the "correct" position.


So, I'm essentially looking for an approach to find the best pattern match of 'my_start_coords' in the reference coordinates, without using 'my_final_coords'. I hope that clearify things.

Comment: I don't understand then.  You describe the open circles, and blue dots as your "start" positions. And presumably you know the locations in 2D space of some of your final positions (red dots)? I interpreted that to mean that you could minimize the sum of distances between those starting locations and final locations to estimate your x/y deltas.  I think maybe you're confusing yourself since your variable names don't match your comments in your code. If that's the case and your red dots are your starting points it's just a matter of swapping the variables in the minimization function.

Comment: I've edited the solution above to reflect what I assume you originally meant by your variable names, not your comments. Does that fit your situation more closely?

Comment: Sorry again, several sloppy mistakes. I now made it clearer that red is start position and blue is my goal. I want to find the red position that in this case best matches the pattern of the blue). So I wanted a good searching strategy to test where in the *reference data* the my_coords_start fits best. In this case that position is illustrated with the blue dots.

Comment: So.. in other words the solution I've implemented in the revised answer is doing what you would like (by switching the application of the delta x/y parameters to the starting location vector)?

Comment: But in your function you are using 'my_coords_final', which essentaly is the solution. It is 'ref_coords' that is the original grid, and where I want to search for a position where 'my_coords_start' is matched the best. In effect, delete 'my_coords_final' and try to recreate it using the two other data frames! Thanks for sticking with me, I again apologize for being unclear...